# Dockerfile gives error when space is used on ubuntu

Tags: docker, sap-commerce-cloud

```
Step 9/10 : RUN . ./setantenv.sh && ant clean all
 ---> Running in 10b2423a32ab
/bin/sh: ./setantenv.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have used that command in dockerfile

```
RUN . ./setantenv.sh && ant clean all
```

but it does not see first `.` and gives an error.

What can I do?

Comment: Does `setantenv.sh` exist inside the container in the directory specified by `WORKDIR` (defaults to `/`), what is the first line of this shell script (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`), and what is the base image you are using? Providing the full Dockerfile would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this in your dockerfile : `ADD ./setantenv.sh /tmp/.` and after `RUN /tmp/setantenv.sh`